# How to fetch next n rows in Hive on Hue Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, cloudera-cdh, hue

Actually as Hive doesn't support OFFSET(not sure) and I have limit my query result to 10 rows.  I want to view only 10 rows output at a time on web, so on page 1, 10 rows will be seen and further next 10 rows to be fetched for page 2 and this goes on till the rows are completed.  So, how can this be achieved in Hue Cloudera using HiveQL?

```
select * from mytable LIMIT 10;
```

Please help me fetch next 10 rows from `mytable`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use row_number() for this.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by id) as rowid FROM mytable
) temp
WHERE rowid > 0 and rowid <= 20;
```